# array declared with static keyword: what is static, the pointer or the whole array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, static

Simple but tricky question:

```
void f() {
    static int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    ...
```

What is static here?  The pointer to array or the whole array?

Can anybody point me to definition of that in the C standard?

Thanks!

Comment: What pointer are you referring to?

Comment: I'm refering to the "a" pointer (&a[0]).

Comment: The expression `&a[0]` to which `a` expands in almost all contexts is not an lvalue. It is an address and not a pointer. There is only one identifier defined and this is the array. Since there is no other identifier, there is nothing to apply the `static` to.

Comment: it seems that even without static keyword here the array a won't change across different calls. Is that standard or just compiler-specific?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the ISO C99 standard (section 6.2.1, "Scopes of identifiers"):

> 3 If the declaration of a file scope
>   identifier for an object or a function
>   contains the storage-class
>   specifier static, the identifier has
>   internal linkage.22)

In your example it's the `a` identifier that becomes static (i.e. the symbol in the object file is not exported).

EDIT:

For non-file scope static declarations (section 6.2.4, "Storage durations of objects")

> 3 An object whose identifier is
>   declared with external or internal
>   linkage, or with the storage-class
>   specifier static has static storage
>   duration. Its lifetime is the entire
>   execution of the program and its
>   stored value is initialized only once,
>   prior to program startup.

I take it this to mean that the array itself becomes static in this case, which makes sense, since the identifier would have invalid contents otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I edited the post to surround it by a function. It is actually not a file scope identifier...

Comment: Yes - the  "object" in this case is the array itself, so it is the array that has static storage duration.

Answer (score 2):

In code:

```
static int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
```

Type for a is not pointer, but array of int. However, it is automatically converted into pointer, e.g. in C standard:

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator,or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

So if a is array, than = { 1, 2, 3 } is it's initialization, not some kind of separate array. I don't know if it's specified exactly somewhere, but in this sense it is used throughout the standard.

**Edit** to clear up confusion by some of readers: according to cited standard, if you write:

```
int arr[4] = { };
arr[0] = 1; //arr here has here type int*
size_t sz = sizeof(arr); //here it is not type int*, sizeof is exception
```

Comment: Did I miss where you answered the question that was asked?

Comment: Question was: What is static here? The pointer to array or the whole array? That implies that static int a[3] -> a is just static int *, actual data (3 integers) are not static, question was about that, static storage looks to be clear to the asker.

Comment: Agh... You are so much obsessed with if "a" is pointer or not that you forgot to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

It applies to the array.  There is no pointer in your code.  Array is not pointer.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void f() {
    static int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
        a[1]++;
        printf("%d\n", a[1]);
}

main()
{
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
                f();
        }
}
```

outputs

```
3
4
5
6
7
```

Comment: -1: wrong, heap-allocated array IS pointer, non-heap-allocated array (with constant size) is not pointer, but automatically converts to - so it is almost pointer (in most cases it's used like one)

Comment: @peenut: What do you mean by a heap-allocated array? Why is it any more of a pointer than an array allocated any other way?

Comment: @peenut um... pointers are not arrays.  Even according to what you say, this array is not a pointer.  I also don't understand what a "heap allocated array" is.

Comment: @peenut also may I recommend that you read http://www.amazon.com/Expert-Programming-Peter-van-Linden/dp/0131774298

Comment: @peenut: You're the one who's wrong; there is no heap-allocated array in this code, and more importantly, no pointer in this code. The fact that you use a pointer to point to an object allocated by `malloc` is irrelevant here.

Comment: in C, array is pointer, sorry that's what C or C++ programmers usually agree about; besides, this obviously lead to the question; if anybody would stick to your naming, there is only array with constant size, right? And i cited standard in my answer - array with constant size is *always* converted to pointer unless special circumstances, please read that

Comment: @peenut stay focused.  *what is heap allocated array*?  Show it to me. Regarding what "usually agree about" -- that's a common misconception.  Arrays are similar to pointers but they are not the same thing.

Comment: @peenut please read through http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html before attempting to comment on this topic again.

Comment: arrays and pointers are not same in sizeof, declarations, etc. everywhere in expressions they are same, it's obvious

Comment: @peenut 1) you just went from "they are the same" to "they are the same under some circumstances".  2) you are still wrong.  they are not the same in expressions. declare an array char a[10] and pointer char *p; you can do p = a; but can't do a = p;

Comment: This answer clarifies everything simply. It should be accepted one. By the way, why did @peenut's answer got any +1s?